# SSH error when launching nodes on another machine

Tags: ros, roslaunch, multiplemachines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We added this line to our launch file in order to run a node on another machine:

```
<machine name="robot" address="robot.dynamic.edu" env-loader="/opt/ros/groovy/env.sh" user="turtlebot"/>
```

The problem is we get this error:

```
robot.dynamic.edu is not in your SSH known_hosts file.

Please manually:
   ssh turtlebot@robot.dynamic.edu

then try roslaunching again.

If you wish to configure roslaunch to automatically recognize unknown hosts, please set the environment variable ROSLAUNCH_SSH_UNKNOWN=1
```

Our environment variable is set to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/env.sh.in

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
   /bin/echo "Usage: env.sh COMMANDS"
   /bin/echo "Calling env.sh without arguments is not supported anymore. Instead spawn a subshell and source a setup file manually."
   exit 1
else
  . "/opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh"
  exec "$@"
fi
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72493/ssh-error-when-launching-nodes-on-another-machine/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Linux doesn't know what computer robot.dynamic.edu refers to, and so you have to tell it. You do so by editing your /etc/hosts file like they do in [this explanation](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/159).

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1